# Object mapping with RestKit

Tags: objective-c, restkit

I am fairly new to RestKit framework. I am facing difficulty in parsing some JSON response.

```
{
    "success": "1",
    "loginStatus": "Success",
    "sessionToken": "NTE5YTg5NjE4ZDIxYzQ3YzMUybdtsUU8989GVmaW5lZHwxMzY5ODE0MTc4Mzgw",
    "user": {
        "ActivationMethod": false,
        "ActivationToken": "iey4C5E3iMt7mXZL",
        "Active": true,
        "FirstName": "John",
        "LastName": "Doe",
}
}
```

This is response of my Login web service.

What I want is to have value of sessionToken, FirstName and LastName to be mapped in one class. For this I have created a class User

```
@interface User : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* firstName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* lastName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* sessionToken;

@end
```

For the mapping I have tried following code :

```
  RKObjectMapping* mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[User class]];
  [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
   @"FirstName": @"firstName",
   @"LastName": @"lastName",
   @"sessionToken" : @"sessionToken",
   }];

 RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping pathPattern:@"/login" keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

  [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
```

Using this I getting values of Lastname and Firstname as null.

The url is http://[BASE URL]/login

I have gone through this [link](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping) on object mapping but could resolve this issue.

Any pointers in this regard will be very helpful

Regards,

tek3

********************** *EDIT* ************************

I am now able to get the values using code below.

```
 RKObjectMapping* userMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[User class] ];
  [userMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
   @"FirstName": @"firstName",
   @"LastName": @"lastName",
   }];


  RKObjectMapping* loginMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Login class] ];
  [loginMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
   @"sessionToken": @"sessionToken",
   }];

  [loginMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"user"
                                                                                 toKeyPath:@"user"
                                                                               withMapping:userMapping]];


  RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:loginMapping pathPattern:@"/login" keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

But I still have one confusion. I had to create another Login as

```
@interface Login : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* sessionToken;
@property (nonatomic, strong) User* user;

@end
```

Login is having an object of User class as property. Is there any way that I get values of all the keys in JSON response by simply creating a single object and not multiple nested objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the original mapping with a single class you could do:

```
RKObjectMapping* mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[User class]];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
@"user.FirstName": @"firstName",
@"user.LastName": @"lastName",
@"sessionToken" : @"sessionToken",
}];
```